# lodash assign a field in each object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array that contains a lot of objects that looks like this:

```
obj = {name: 'Hello', isUpdated:false};
```

Now, I wish to use `lodash` to assign all `isUpdated` variables from `false` to `true`.

I have been looking at their documentation and found:

```
_.assignIn(object, [sources])
```

However, I'm not quite sure it's what I needed. Maybe I need to combine two different methods?

I was hoping that some of you guys may know, thanks.

Comment: Can you add complete array and the expected array.

Comment: `arr = arr.map(function(o) { o.isUpdated = true; return o; });`

Comment: The above will modify the original array even without reassigning. A more explicit way to do this would be `arr.forEach(o => o.isUpdated = true);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to mutate the source array, then you can use *[_.assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign)* together with *[_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map)*.

```
var result = _.map(array, v => _.assign({}, v, { isUpdated: true }));
```

```js
var array = [{
  name: 'hoo',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'yeah',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'Hello',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'Hello',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'Hello',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'yeahv',
  isUpdated: false
}];

var result = _.map(array, v => _.assign({}, v, { isUpdated: true }));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

A vanilla JS alternative would be to use *[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)* with *[Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)*

```
var result = array.map(v => Object.assign({}, v, { isUpdated: true }));
```

```js
var array = [{
  name: 'hoo',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'yeah',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'Hello',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'Hello',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'Hello',
  isUpdated: false
}, {
  name: 'yeahv',
  isUpdated: false
}];

var result = array.map(v => Object.assign({}, v, { isUpdated: true }));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Tushar said in his comment, you don't actually need Lodash if you're in a reasonably modern browser, the array object has it's own `map` function that'll do the trick <s>(and Lodash iirc uses it under the hood if present).</s>

In any case, to answer you for Lodash, I'd use `_.map()` as well:

```
_.map(arr, (o) => { o.isUpdated = true; return o});
```

Comment: Lodash doesn't use the native [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as it is slow. Here's the [reference](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L602).

Comment: OK, thanks, I couldn't recall for sure. I knew they used native stuff in some cases, and not others.